# Facebook Login for Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: c#, facebook, authentication, windows-phone, windows-phone-8.1

I am trying to figure out a simple code for logging in facebook from a Windows Phone 8.1 app (C#).

As the `Facebook Client` from NuGet doesn't target Windows Phone 8.1, it seems I'd have to write some extra code. As I read **[in this facebook post](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/login-for-windows-phone#login)**, I'd need to launch an Uri to invoke the Login Dialog. That much, I managed to do :

```
 await Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(FacebookUri.DisplayLoginDialog);
```

where DisplayLoginDialog is a static string object with the required necessary data on the request (appId, productId, permissions, etc). I was redirected to the facebook app, to accept that my app requires such permissions.

And I accepted.

So what now? How do I get a response or something with the `access_token`? I have researched a lot for this but I wasn't able to find relevant posts.

The same facebook link from above, says at the section of *Handling the Login Dialog* that :

*If someone successfully logs in, the URI association of your app will be automatically triggered, meaning they will be sent to your app, along with an access token:*

```
msft-{ProductID}://authorize/?
access_token={user-access-token}&
expires_in={expiration-time-of-token}
```

But I am confused on how to actually use this in C#.

How do I get a response with the `access token` after the login suceeded or and `error code` and `error message` if it failed, like it is written in the facebook post?

Comment: Check out these code samples, might help: http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Web-Authentication-d0485122

Comment: Please look into this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40542131/facebook-single-sign-on-not-working-in-windows-phone-8-1-app-running-on-windows

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the Package.appxmanifest file, go to 'Declarations' Tab and add a Protocol Declaration.

In the Name Field, enter your Microsoft product id as 'msft-PRODUCT_ID' [product id without dashes].

In the App.xaml.cs file, add the following code

```
    protected override void OnActivated(IActivatedEventArgs args)
    {
        if (args.Kind == ActivationKind.Protocol)
        {
            ProtocolActivatedEventArgs eventArgs = args as ProtocolActivatedEventArgs;

            Uri responseUri = eventArgs.Uri;

           //Now you can use responseUri to retrieve the access token and expiration time of token

        }

        base.OnActivated(args);
    }
```

Comment: Thank you very much! In the meantime I've used the WebAuthenticationBroker in order to connect to Facebook service and retrieve the access_token. But this is exactly what I needed, to use the Facebook App instead and delegate all the work to it.

Comment: The only drawback with this is I've introduced some unwanted coupling between UI and App.xaml.cs... In the code-behind of one of my views, I am calling the UriLauncher.LaunchAsync and the response is handled as part of the AppActivated event handler. In the code-behind I can't know when the operation is complete (in order to navigate to a different view), so the navigation is trigged in App.xaml.cs via something like this : rootFrame.Navigate(typeof(MyPage))

Comment: When I open Package.appxmanifest and go to the Declarations tab, the Protocol Declaration is not available in the drop down list? Is there another step I need to take prior to this?

Comment: Also, No suitable method to override (OnActivated), and the ProtocolActivatedEventArgs doesn't seem to exists, even if I am `using Windows.ApplicationModel.Activation`.

Comment: open Package.appxmanifest in text editor and add Extensions element under Application Tag

      <Extensions>
        <Extension Category="windows.protocol">
          <Protocol Name="msft-{productID}" />
        </Extension>
      </Extensions>

Hope this helps!

Comment: Well, I can add the declaration now, but I still get the other problems:
"`ProtocolActivatedEventArgs` could not be found" and
"`System.Windows.Application` does not contain a definition for `OnActivated`".

Comment: I tried the above code, problem is OnActivated Event is not triggered when   facebook app redirects to my app.Please help.

Comment: @MohanRajNK above code works fine in windows phone 8.1 devices. But its not working for windows 10 devices. Have you run this code in windows  10 devices?

Comment: @MohanRajNK please refer this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40542131/facebook-single-sign-on-not-working-in-windows-phone-8-1-app-running-on-windows

Answer (score 0):

You might want to take a look at this: [Sign into Windows Phone 8 apps with Facebook Login](http://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2013/11/14/sign-into-windows-phone-8-apps-with-facebook-login/).

This tutorial on the Microsoft blogs shows you how you can tie directly into the Facebook app from your app like many do on Android and iOS.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. I have studied those tutorials, and I am sort of a familiar with them (I've used Facebook.Client on Win8). The actual issue I am confronting is that Facebook.Client on NuGet targets WP 8.0, and I'd need something for WP 8.1. I've seen other posts like this as well, I'm not the only one... I'll either wait for a port or having a look over the source code...