# Facebook Login in Windows Phone 8.1 App

Tags: facebook, windows-phone-8.1, facebook-login

App Manifest
Configure your app’s manifest file `WMAppManifest.xml` to register a custom URI scheme that is of the form `msft-{ProductID}`, where `{ProductID}` is your app’s product ID (without dashes). It should look like this:

```
<Protocol Name="msft-43245dd584d84cde837aa19a4a2e3914" NavUriFragment="encodedLaunchUri=%s" TaskID="_default" />
```

Where to add this line in Windows Phone 8.1 App `Package.appxmanifest`?

It shows:

```
Protocol not found in namespace
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add protocol inside the extension element like the following

```
...
<Application Id="">
  <Extensions>
    <Extension Category="windows.protocol">
      <Protocol Name="msft-43245dd584d84cde837aa19a4a2e3914" />
    </Extension>
  <Extensions>
...
```

Or you can open Appmanifest file in editor and configure it as mentioned here [Facebook Login for Windows Phone 8.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25168525/facebook-login-for-windows-phone-8-1/26955236#26955236)