# How can I retrieve the user-access-token when logging in via Facebook in my windows phone 8.1 app?

Tags: c#, cordova, windows-phone, windows-phone-8.1, facebook-login

I'm trying to implement Facebook login in my cordova app. It works in iPhone and Android, but I can't get it to work on Windows Phone 8.1.

What I'm doing now for Windows phone 8.1 is to call a cordova plugin that I made which does the following:

```
string loginUrl = "fbconnect://authorize" +
    "?client_id=CLIENTID" +
    "&scope=public_profile,email" +
    "&redirect_uri=msft-APPID://authorize";
var uri = new Uri(loginUrl);
var success = await Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(uri);
```

This brings up the facebook app a very short amount of time, then my app resumes.

The facebook documentation says that they resume my app the same way I call the facebook app, but with a different `loginUrl`, containing different parameters.

Either:

```
msft-{APPID}://authorize/?
    access_token={user-access-token}&
```

Or:

```
msft-{AppID}://authorize/?
  error=access_denied&
  error_code=200&
  error_description=Permissions%20Error&
  error_reason=user_denied
```

I am trying to retrieve that `{user-access-token}` or `error_reason` when my app resumes.

I know the `Application_Activated` (app.xaml.cs) method is called, but the arguments passed to it don't contain any of this. How do I get these values?

Comment: I think this is what you probably need http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25168525/facebook-login-for-windows-phone-8-1/26955236#26955236

Comment: I think that link is a duplicate question I hadn't found. Unfortunately the accepted answer doesn't work for me...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Windows Phone 8.1 Silverlight you can handle this using the **UriMapperBase**. Here's a good introduction to UriMapperBase and it shows what it is and how it can be used: http://bsubramanyamraju.blogspot.fi/2014/06/windowsphone-8-custom-uri.html

Also, here's step-by-step tutorial on how to implement Facebook login in a Windows Phone Silverlight app using a custom UriMapperBase: http://doli.us/facebook-login-with-windows-phone-8/

**Updated with more details**

Your UriMapperBase is executed before the app's first navigation happens. There's multiple ways how you can handle this but one option is just to add static property to your App.xaml.cs:

```
        public static string AccessToken { get; set; }
```

Then, in your custom UriMapper, parse the received data and set it to the AccessToken property:

```
public class AccessTokenParser : UriMapperBase
{
    public override void MapUri(Uri uri)
    {
        var url = uri.ToString();        
        if (url.Contains("access_token"))
        {
            App.AccessToken = ParseAccessTokenFromUrl(url); // Your code here
        }
        return new Uri("/MainPage.xaml", UriKind.Relative);
    }
}
```

Now, in your MainPage.xaml.cs, you can override the OnNavigatedTo-method:

```
    public partial class MainPage : PhoneApplicationPage
    {

      protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
      {
          if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(App.AccessToken))
            return;

          DoThingsWithAccessToken();
      }
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: The first link you mention tells me to override the OnNavigatedTo method. Many solutions out there suggest this. However they don't say in which file to add it. I guess they mean App.xaml.cs, yet when I add this method, I get an error: "no suitable method found to override". Is there something I need to do before this?

Comment: Ah! I didn't even know there was a cs file hidden in MainPage.xaml. Success! That was the problem, I was overriding `OnNavigatedTo` in the wrong class.